# Convert Hex String to BYTE Array in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the simplest way to convert this string: 
`string strHex = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";`

In this BYTE array: 
`BYTE bArray[] = { 0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };`

Thank you!

Comment: SO is **not** a code writing service. Please show your attempts, with explanations of what's not working in your solution.

Comment: The simplest way is to have a go at it, get it working asking StackOverflow for help when appropriate (that means not asking for debugging help) and then posting to code review to ask for suggestions on how to improve

Comment: It was my last alternative. I have tried a lot, I've searched in this forum and google and I can't. I will add my attempts. Thank for your help.

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
    for(auto it = strHex.begin(); it < strHex.end() - 1; it += 2) {
        bytes.push_back(std::stoi(std::string(it, it + 2), 0, 16));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I use the xxd tool to convert a desired file of arbitrary data into compilable byte arrays.

```
echo Good data > good.bin
xxd -i good.bin > good_bin.cpp
clang++ -c good_bin.cpp
```